# backup new data in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a `MySQL` database with some tables that every day some records are added to each table. I have developed a `shell script` containing `mysqldump` command to backup this database every day from the first record in each table. I want to know if there is a way to backup newly generated data in database not all data from the first record.

Comment: Have you considered reading the chapter of the MySQL manual titled [Backup and Recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/backup-and-recovery.html)?

Comment: @eggyal Yes. I have had a look at it but it could not help me.

Comment: Why not?  It tells you exactly how to perform incremental backups, as quoted in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [Backup and Recovery Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/backup-methods.html#idm139832248474096):

> #### Making Incremental Backups by Enabling the Binary Log
>
> MySQL supports incremental backups: You must start the server with the [`--log-bin`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) option to enable binary logging; see [Section 6.4.4, “The Binary Log”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/binary-log.html). The binary log files provide you with the information you need to replicate changes to the database that are made subsequent to the point at which you performed a backup. At the moment you want to make an incremental backup (containing all changes that happened since the last full or incremental backup), you should rotate the binary log by using [`FLUSH LOGS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/flush.html). This done, you need to copy to the backup location all binary logs which range from the one of the moment of the last full or incremental backup to the last but one. These binary logs are the incremental backup; at restore time, you apply them as explained in [Section 8.5, “Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery Using the Binary Log”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/point-in-time-recovery.html). The next time you do a full backup, you should also rotate the binary log using [`FLUSH LOGS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/flush.html) or [**mysqldump --flush-logs**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html). See [Section 5.5.4, “**mysqldump** — A Database Backup Program”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html).

Answer (score 1):

You won't get incremental backups with mysqldump, but you could enable binary logging and then grab the logs occasionally.  Obviously you'll need a clean, fairly recent copy of the data files as well.  Take a look at the manual for more info and strategies: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-and-recovery.html

Answer (score 1):

### Option A: Log

You could have MySQL write a (binary) log of all executed insert/update statements and replay that in case of a recovery. This is also recommended by MySQL for disaster recovery (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log.html).

Viewing and recovering is done using the `mysqlbinlog` tool, the output of which you could directly pass to `mysql` to have the statements executed.

If you go for this strategy, make sure to get MySQL to roll over the binary log to a new file once you do a full dump of the database, to make sure that only new changes after the backup end up in the binlog.

### Option B: record timestamp

Some systems update a timestamp in the row each time they update it. If your software does that, you can just use that, or you can add your own column and update it via a database trigger that is executed for every update/insert. Keep in mind however that this may slow down operations, so especially for batch processing of huge data sets, you should probably find a different solution.